# track vehicle trajectory by using opencv

Tags: opencv

This question bothers me for a long time. The basic vehicle counting program includes: 1. recognize a vehicle. 2. track the vehicle by features.

However, if the vehicle #1 was found at time t, then at t+1 the program start to track the vehicle, but #1 can also be found by recognizing process, then t+2 program two vehicles will be tracked, but actually just one #1 in the frame. How can the recognized vehicle avoiding duplicate detect?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you are concerned about detecting the object that you are already tracking (lack of detector/tracker communication). In that case you can either:

- **Pre-check** - during detection exclude the areas, where you already track objects or
- **Post-check** - discard detected objects, that are near tracked ones (if "selective" detection is not possible for your approach for some reason)

There are several possible implementations.

1. **Mask**. Create a binary mask, where areas near tracked objects are "marked" (e.g. ones near tracked objects and zeros everywhere else). Given such a mask, before detection in particular location you can quickly check if something is being tracked there, and abort detection (**Pre-check** approach) or remove detected object, if you stick with the **Post-check** approach.
2. **Brute-force**. Calculate distances between particular location and each of the tracked ones (you can also check overlapping area and other characteristics). You can then discard detections, that are too close and/or similar to already tracked objects.

Lets consider which way is better (and when).

1. **Mask** needs O(**N**) operations to add all tracked objects to the mask and O(**M**) operations to check all locations of interest. That's O(**N** + **M**) = O(max(**N**, **M**)), where **N** is number of tracked objects and **M** is number of checked locations (detected objects, for example). Which number (**N** or **M**) will be bigger depends on your application. Additional memory is also needed to hold the binary mask (usually it is not very important, but again, it depends on the application).
2. **Brute-force** needs O(**N** * **M**) operations (each of **M** locations is checked against **N** candidates). It doesn't need additional memory, and allows doing more complex logic during checks. For example, if object suddenly changes size/color/whatever within one frame - we should probably not track it (since it may be a completely different object occluding original one) and do something else instead.

To sum up:

1. **Mask** is asymptotically better when you have a lot of objects. It is almost essential if you do something like a sliding window search during detection, and can exclude some areas (since in this case you will likely have a large **M**). You will likely use it with **Pre-check**.
2. **Brute-force** is OK when you have few objects and need to do checks that involve different properties. It makes most sense to use it with **Post-check**.

If you happen to need something inbetween - you'll have to be more creative and either encode object properties in mask somehow (to achieve constant look-up time) or use more complex data structures (to speed up "Brute-force" search).