# Marking a detected object through Masking

Tags: python, opencv, tracking, object-detection

I was following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40207763/track-vehicle-trajectory-by-using-opencv) link, to solve a [problem of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45584199/object-tracking-on-image). In the first link, it mentioned, we can create a "mask" and if the next object is very near to that "mask", we will not detect it, as it might be the same object. But if it has a distance, we should detect it and then track it till the end.

But I'm not getting how to create the mask and use the conditional statement to exclude it. So, there's first issue of creating the mask. If I can create the mask of the object, then I can try to exclude it from the next detection.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

cap = cv2.VideoCapture('anyvideo.mp4')

while(1):

    # Take each frame
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    if ret:

        # detect the object  and get contour of the image. I'm calling it bbox

        tracker = cv2.Tracker_create("KCF")
        ok = tracker.init(frame, tuple(bbox))
        ok, bbox = tracker.update(frame)
        p1 = (int(bbox[0]), int(bbox[1]))
        p2 = (int(bbox[0] + bbox[2]), int(bbox[1] + bbox[3]))
        cv2.rectangle(frame, p1, p2, (0,0,255))
        cv2.putText(frame, 'Tracked', (x + 25,y + 10), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,1, (255,255,255), 2, cv2.LINE_AA)
        mask = np.full((frame.shape[0], frame.shape[1]), 0, dtype=np.uint8)
        res = res.append(cv2.bitwise_and(frame,frame,mask = mask))


        k = cv2.waitKey(5) & 0xFF
        if k == 27:
            break
    else:
        break
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, take a image for the **reference** without object, with the same background. Then **subtract** the image in which the object is present. It will will give you some value, expect zero, where the object is present. Perform **binary threshold** on it. Now you would have the object alone. Use that as a **mask**.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've created the mask and updated the code accordingly. Now how can I use it as filter for removing already tracked images.

Comment: As I suggested earlier, `Perform binary threshold on it.`, after this you can take contour of it. Calculate the center of mass of it and crop the appropriate region of the object. With the center of mass, you can calculate the relative position. And rest of the algorithm depends on your own logic. You can use any algorithm or your own logic to track the object.

Comment: @arijit, if you need any help, you can ask. If you find this answer helpful and up-vote it and select as answer.

Comment: Actually  I was trying your options. But till now I didn't succeed. So I didn't mark your answer.

Comment: Now where are you facing problem?